# Creating a table in a narrow space

Tags: tables, moderncv

I'm working with moderncv and having difficulties when creating a table in a narrow space. 
How to make the table properly?

**Edited:**

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}

    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

    \newcounter{tabenum}
    \newcommand\tabitem{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.}

    \moderncvstyle{casual} 
    \moderncvcolor{blue} 

    \usepackage{lipsum} 

    \usepackage[scale=0.75,margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
    \firstname{} 
    \familyname{} 

    \address{}
    \mobile{}
    \phone{}
    \fax{}
    \email{}
    \homepage{}
    \extrainfo{}

    \quote{}

    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

    \setlength\tabcolsep{3.25pt}

    \begin{document}

    \makecvtitle 

    \section{Riwayat Pekerjaan}

    \cvline{Riwayat Kepangkatan dan Golongan Ruang Penggajian}{\small\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \setcounter{tabenum}{0}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{\hskip\labelsep}ccclllll@{}}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{{No.}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Pangkat}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Gol. Ruang}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Berlaku TMT}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Gaji Pokok}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Surat Keputusan}}                                                                       \\\cline{6-8}
                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                     &                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Pejabat}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Nomor}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Tanggal}} \\
    \midrule[1pt]\addlinespace
    \tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (CPNS) & 1 Jan 1991 & 56.080 & Mendikbud & 4700/A2.IV.1/C/1991 & 21/01/1991 \\
    \tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (PNS) & 1 Nov 1992 & 70.100 & Mendikbud & 356/B/CI/SP & 31/10/1992 \\
    \tabitem & Pengatur Tingkat I & II/d & 1 Okt 1994 & 148.700 & BAKN & II.13-23/05021/KEP/X/1994 & 03/06/1996 \\
    \end{tabular}}
    \setcounter{tabenum}{0}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: if possible set the `\hintscolumnwidth` a bit narrower and then play around with the column sizes. Or reformat the table. If you need to, search the side on how to change the font size for a table. Please note that you do not have to set the multirows in you your last line. Just if you have to. But do not set a width here, as this would be doubled. Just use `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a compromise: I reduced `hintscolumnwidth` to `3.25cm` and `tabcolsep` to `2.6pt`. Another solution would be to keep 3.85cm for \hintscolwidth, have 4pt for \tabcolsep and use `\footnotesize` for the table. I used the `showframe` option of `geometry` to check if the table lies between the margins.

To simplify the code I used the `makecell`: it defines a `\thead` command that supports `\\` in cells and common formatting — here \ bfseries. For two of the cells that were really too wide, I used `\makecell` ang split the contents of the cells into two lines — hope your specifications allow that. I also loaded `booktabs` to use its variable thickness for horizontal rules.

I have two ways to obtain a nice looking result: one uses the `\multirowcell/\multirowthead`, from the `makecell` package, which has a simpler syntax than the original multirow, and retains the common formatting; the other doesn't use any multirow, but the `\stackon` command from the `stackengine` package.

Finally, as I suppose the number in the first column corresponds to an enumeration I emulated this with a `tabenum` counter and a `tabitem` command (inspired by the `listliketab` package.

```
     \documentclass[10pt,a4paper, sans, showframe, nomarginpar]{moderncv}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %%\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}

    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadalign{cb}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{lt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells

    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \setstackEOL{;}

    \newcounter{tabenum}
    \newcommand\tabitem{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.}

    \moderncvstyle{casual}
    \moderncvcolor{blue}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage[scale=0.75,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
    \firstname{}
    \familyname{}

    \address{}
    \mobile{}
    \phone{}
    \fax{}
    \email{}
    \homepage{}
    \extrainfo{}

    \quote{}

    \begin{document}

    \makecvtitle

    \section{Riwayat Pekerjaan}

    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.25cm} \setlength\tabcolsep{2.6pt}
\cvline{Riwayat Kepangkatan dan Golongan Ruang Penggajian}{\small%\
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{\hskip\labelsep}ccclllll@{}}
\multirowthead{3}{No.} & \multirowthead{3}{Pangkat}& \multirowthead{3}{Gol. Ruang} & \multirowthead{3}{Berlaku TMT} & \multirowthead{3}{Gaji Pokok} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\thead{Surat Keputusan}} \\\cmidrule(lr{6pt}){6-8}
                              & & & & & \thead{Pejabat} & \thead{Nomor} & \thead{Tanggal} \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{1-6}\cmidrule[1pt](lr{4pt}){6-8}
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (CPNS) & 1 Jan 1991 & 56.080 & Mendikbud & 4700/A2.IV.1/C/1991 & 21/01/1991 \\
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (PNS) & 1 Nov 1992 & 70.100 & Mendikbud & 356/B/CI/SP & 31/10/1992 \\
\tabitem & \makecell{Pengatur\\ Tingkat I} & II/d & 1 Okt 1994 & 148.700 & BAKN & \makecell{II.13-23/05021/\\ KEP/X/1994} & 03/06/1996 \\
    \end{tabular}}\bigskip

\cvline{Riwayat Kepangkatan dan Golongan Ruang Penggajian}{\small%
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{\hskip\labelsep}ccclllll@{}}\\\cmidrule(lr{6pt}){6-8}
\thead{No.} & \thead{Pangkat}& \thead{Gol. Ruang} & \thead{Berlaku TMT} & \thead{Gaji Pokok} & %
                               \thead{Pejabat} & \thead{\smash{\stackon[4ex]{Nomor}{Surat Keputusan}}} & \thead{Tanggal} \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{1-6}\cmidrule[1pt](lr{4pt}){6-8}
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (CPNS) & 1 Jan 1991 & 56.080 & Mendikbud & 4700/A2.IV.1/C/1991 & 21/01/1991 \\
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (PNS) & 1 Nov 1992 & 70.100 & Mendikbud & 356/B/CI/SP & 31/10/1992 \\
\tabitem & \makecell{Pengatur\\ Tingkat I} & II/d & 1 Okt 1994 & 148.700 & BAKN & \makecell{II.13-23/05021/\\ KEP/X/1994} & 03/06/1996 \\
    \end{tabular}}\vspace{1cm}

 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.85cm} \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\cvline{Riwayat Kepangkatan dan Golongan Ruang Penggajian}{\footnotesize%
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{\hskip\labelsep}ccclllll@{}}
\multirowthead{3}{No.} & \multirowthead{3}{Pangkat}& \multirowthead{3}{Gol. Ruang} & \multirowthead{3}{Berlaku TMT} & \multirowthead{3}{Gaji Pokok} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\thead{Surat Keputusan}} \\\cmidrule(lr{0.8em}){6-8}
                              & & & & & \thead{Pejabat} & \thead{Nomor} & \thead{Tanggal} \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{1-6}\cmidrule[1pt](lr{4pt}){6-8}
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (CPNS) & 1 Jan 1991 & 56.080 & Mendikbud & 4700/A2.IV.1/C/1991 & 21/01/1991 \\
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (PNS) & 1 Nov 1992 & 70.100 & Mendikbud & 356/B/CI/SP & 31/10/1992 \\
\tabitem & \makecell{Pengatur\\ Tingkat I} & II/d & 1 Okt 1994 & 148.700 & BAKN & \makecell{II.13-23/05021/\\ KEP/X/1994} & 03/06/1996 \\
\end{tabular}}

\cvline{Riwayat Kepangkatan dan Golongan Ruang Penggajian}{\footnotesize%
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{\hskip\labelsep}ccclllll@{}}\\\cmidrule(lr{6pt}){6-8}
\thead{No.} & \thead{Pangkat}& \thead{Gol. Ruang} & \thead{Berlaku TMT} & \thead{Gaji Pokok} & %
                               \thead{Pejabat} & \thead{\smash{\stackon[4ex]{Nomor}{Surat Keputusan}}} & \thead{Tanggal} \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{1-6}\cmidrule[1pt](lr{0.8em}){6-8}
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (CPNS) & 1 Jan 1991 & 56.080 & Mendikbud & 4700/A2.IV.1/C/1991 & 21/01/1991 \\
\tabitem & Pengatur & II/c (PNS) & 1 Nov 1992 & 70.100 & Mendikbud & 356/B/CI/SP & 31/10/1992 \\
\tabitem & \makecell{Pengatur\\ Tingkat I} & II/d & 1 Okt 1994 & 148.700 & BAKN & \makecell{II.13-23/05021/\\ KEP/X/1994} & 03/06/1996 \\
    \end{tabular}}\bigskip
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write down \cline{6-8} at the end of line 37. And I want to keep \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}, if still possible.

Comment: @kalakay: Here are two variants, one with (almost) 4cm for `\hintscolumnwidth`, playing with `tabcolsep`.

Comment: Please help me, I have a long cell content. (See the code after edited.)

Comment: @kalakay: I've modified my answer, leading to 4 solutions instead of 2. I hope some two-line cells are OK

Comment: Answered! Thank you, it was solved with the font size and \makecell.